# "Match error: Expected string, got undefined" Recover Password

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts, user-accounts

```js
Template.ResetPwd.events({
    'submit #forgot-password': function(event, template) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var forgotPasswordForm = $(event.currentTarget),
            email = forgotPasswordForm.find('#forgotPasswordEmail').val().toLowerCase();
        if (email !== "") {
            Accounts.forgotPassword({
                email: email
            }, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    if (err.message === 'User not found [403]') {
                        console.log('This email does not exist.');
                        FlashMessages.sendSuccess(err.message, {
                            autoHide: true,
                            hideDelay: 8000
                        });
                    } else {
                        console.log('We are sorry but something went wrong.');
                        FlashMessages.sendSuccess('We are sorry but something went wrong', {
                            autoHide: true,
                            hideDelay: 8000
                        });
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log('Email Sent. Check your mailbox.');
                    FlashMessages.sendSuccess('Email Sent', {
                        autoHide: true,
                        hideDelay: 4000
                    });
                }
            });

        } else {
            template.find('#form-messages').html('Email Invalido');
        }
        return false;
    }
});


if (Accounts._resetPasswordToken) {
    Session.set('resetPassword', Accounts._resetPasswordToken);
};

Template.setNewPass.helpers({
    resetPassword: function() {
        return Session.get('resetPassword');
    }
});

Template.setNewPass.events({
    'submit #set-new-password': function(e, template) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // var target = event.target;
        // var password = target.resetpass.value;
        // var passwordConfirm = target.verificy.value;

    var resetPasswordForm = $(e.currentTarget),
        password = resetPasswordForm.find('#resetPasswordPassword').val(),
        passwordConfirm = resetPasswordForm.find('#resetPasswordPasswordConfirm').val();
        // if (isNotEmpty(password) && areValidPasswords(password, passwordConfirm)) {
        if (password === passwordConfirm) {
            Accounts.resetPassword(Session.get('resetPassword'), password, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('We are sorry but something went wrong.');
                    FlashMessages.sendSuccess(err, {
                        autoHide: true,
                        hideDelay: 8000
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log('Your password has been changed. Welcome back!');
                    FlashMessages.sendSuccess('Your password has been changed. Welcome back', {
                        autoHide: true,
                        hideDelay: 8000
                    });
                    Session.set('resetPassword', null);
                }
            });
        } else {
            FlashMessages.sendSuccess('contraseñas no son iguales', {
                autoHide: true,
                hideDelay: 8000
            });
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

```html
<template name="ResetPwd">
      <div class="container">
        <p>
          {{> flashMessages}}
        </p>
    <form id="forgot-password">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input class="inputStyle" type="text" id="forgotPasswordEmail" name="email" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input class="btn-main" type="submit" value="Recuperar Contraseña">
        </div>
          <p id="form-messages"></p>
    </form>
    </div>

</template>
  <template name="setNewPass">
    <div class="container">
      <p>
        {{> flashMessages}}
      </p>
        <div class="row">
            <form id="set-new-password">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <input class="inputStyle" type="password" name="resetpass" id="resetPasswordPassword" placeholder="contraseña">
                      <input class="inputStyle" type="password" name="verificy" id="resetPasswordPasswordConfirm" placeholder="verificar contraseña">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <input class="btn-main" type="submit" name="some_name" value="Recuperar Contraseña">
                </div>
                 <p id="form-messages"></p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
  </template>
```

Hello, I'm having trouble retrieving the password when sending the email with the token to retrieve it I receive it successfully then I press that url

> http://localhost:1999/reset/_M5swGv9Uwn--4_olB0itOuYBLGMYYgDMQB9es9Y0TM

And it directs me to the window to change the password and I enter the new password there is where I get the following error errorClass

> errorType : "Match.Error" message : "Match error: Expected string, got
>   undefined" path : "" sanitizedError : errorClass

In my code I have the following.

Comment: does $('#forgotPasswordEmail').val() work?

Comment: If it works try both ways because I understand the error is that my data not as they are not string does not take.

Do not you know what the problem might be?